# Using gulpjs in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, gulp

I need to compress and minify js on the fly from php. Would it be better to call grunt from the `exec` function like this:

PHP code

```
// create gulpfile.js with needed content
exec('gulp scripts');
// return file to user
```

Or might it be better to have a node server running, and pass off a request to it. I was thinking make a curl request to `localhost:3030` with the post data. I know `exec` has some overhead when creating a new shell, but having a node server might seem more computationally expensive.

Which would be better?

Comment: Having a separate server running sounds like more work for the computer to me.  Have you tested both alternatives?  What were your results?

Comment: Why not just use `gulp.watch` to do the compression & minification when the files change?